# Is there any other blockchain project that implements smart contract

Tags: blockchain

Quite new to blockchain so my question maybe somewhat stupid. I have a blockchain project, where smart contract is required but it also has special requirement such as Proof-of-Importance. I have spent some time coding smart contracts in Ethereum. It's good but according to the project requirement, I have to understand all the Ethereum source code. So I am wondering is there any light-weighted blockchain project that implements smart contract?

Many Thanks.

Comment: `It's good but according to the project requirement, I have to understand all the Ethereum source code.` That seems rather over the top, the full ethereum implementation is not trivial. Moreover, any reasonable system that implements similar functionality will also be non-trivial (but could be a fair bit simpler than ethereum)

Comment: Ethereum's source code base is 200,000 lines. No single person can understand that amount of code

Comment: Smart contract technology can't be lightweight by definition, you have to implement a Virtual Machine, and that's very complicated thing.

Answer (score 1):

Cardano (https://www.cardano.org/en/home/) and EOS (https://eos.io/) are the other blockchain projects that implement (or better said, will implement) smart contract technology.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to understand the Ethereum source code if you would like to learn to write smart contract by using solidity. 
Except Cardano and EOS mentioned by the above, IBM's Hyperledger also implements the smart contract. You could write smart contract by using golang